# WebGL shader program not working

Tags: javascript, debugging, webgl, shader

I was trying to use WebGL for the first time, but I seem to have hit a problem. All the code seems fine, and I have run it through jshint multiple times, but I can't seem to get this program working right. I am running Chrome 54 stable on Chrome OS. Code is below.

```js
"use strict";

//initWebGL function
function initWebGL(canvas){
  //get a webGL context
  var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl") || canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");

  //if we have a context, we're good to go. if not, alert, and return the nothing that is our empty context
  if(!gl){
    alert("Your browser does not support WebGL");
  }
  return gl;
}

//shader creation function
function createShader(gl, type, source){
  //create and compile the shader
  var shader = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(shader, source);
  gl.compileShader(shader);

  //if success, then return the shader. if not, log the shader info, and then delete the shader.
  if(gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)){
    return shader;
  }
  alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader) + "");
  gl.deleteShader(shader);
}

//program creation function
function createProgram(gl, vertexShader, fragmentShader){
  //create the program and attach the shaders
  var program = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
  gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
  gl.linkProgram(program);

  //if success, return the program. if not, log the program info, and delete it.
  if(gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS)){
    return program;
  }
  alert(gl.getProgramInfoLog(program) + "");
  gl.deleteProgram(program);
}

//main function
function start(){
  //get the canvas
  var canvas = document.getElementById("webgl_canvas");

  //initialize WebGL
  var gl = initWebGL(canvas);

  //keep going if we have a context
  if(!gl){
    return;
  }

  //set the clear color
  gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

  //set up depth testing
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL);

  //clear the color and the depth buffer
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  gl.clear(gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  //set up the viewport
  gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  //set up shaders
  var vertexShaderSource = "attribute vec2 a_position; void main(){gl_Position = vec4(a_position, 0, 1);}";
  var fragmentShaderSource = "precision mediump float; void main(){gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 1, 1, 1);}";
  var vertexShader = createShader(gl, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderSource);
  var fragmentShader = createShader(gl, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderSource);

  //set up the program
  var program = createProgram(gl, vertexShader, fragmentShader);

  //get the attribute location
  var positionAttributeLocation = gl.getAttributeLocation(program, "a_position");

  //set up a position buffer
  var positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
  gl.bindBufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.7, 0]));

  //tell webGL to use the program
  gl.useProgram(program);

  //enable the vertex attribute array
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionAttributeLocation);

  //tell webgl how to pull out the data
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionAttributeLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

  //render
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
}
```

```css
canvas{outline:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>WebGL demo</title>
 </head>
 <body onload="start();">
  <canvas id="webgl_canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well… what happens when you try running it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It helps looking up [the api you're programming against](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/), just following the error messages logged to the console (every browser has a different way to bring up the it's developer console. On Chrome it's [View->Developer->JavaScript Console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/). On Firefox it's [Tools->Web Developer->Web Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console). For other Safari [see here](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21491?locale=en_US). For Edge [see here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/f12-devtools-guide/))

`getAttributeLocation` does not exist, you want `getAttribLocation`.

`bindBufferData` does not exist, you want `bufferData` which also requires  the usage hint(used `STATIC_DRAW` here) as third argument.

```js
"use strict";

//initWebGL function
function initWebGL(canvas){
  //get a webGL context
  var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl") || canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");

  //if we have a context, we're good to go. if not, alert, and return the nothing that is our empty context
  if(!gl){
    alert("Your browser does not support WebGL");
  }
  return gl;
}

//shader creation function
function createShader(gl, type, source){
  //create and compile the shader
  var shader = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(shader, source);
  gl.compileShader(shader);

  //if success, then return the shader. if not, log the shader info, and then delete the shader.
  if(gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)){
    return shader;
  }
  alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader) + "");
  gl.deleteShader(shader);
}

//program creation function
function createProgram(gl, vertexShader, fragmentShader){
  //create the program and attach the shaders
  var program = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
  gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
  gl.linkProgram(program);

  //if success, return the program. if not, log the program info, and delete it.
  if(gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS)){
    return program;
  }
  alert(gl.getProgramInfoLog(program) + "");
  gl.deleteProgram(program);
}

//main function
function start(){
  //get the canvas
  var canvas = document.getElementById("webgl_canvas");

  //initialize WebGL
  var gl = initWebGL(canvas);

  //keep going if we have a context
  if(!gl){
    return;
  }

  //set the clear color
  gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

  //set up depth testing
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL);

  //clear the color and the depth buffer
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  gl.clear(gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  //set up the viewport
  gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  //set up shaders
  var vertexShaderSource = "attribute vec2 a_position; void main(){gl_Position = vec4(a_position, 0, 1);}";
  var fragmentShaderSource = "precision mediump float; void main(){gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 1, 1, 1);}";
  var vertexShader = createShader(gl, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderSource);
  var fragmentShader = createShader(gl, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderSource);

  //set up the program
  var program = createProgram(gl, vertexShader, fragmentShader);

  //get the attribute location
  var positionAttributeLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position");

  //set up a position buffer
  var positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.7, 0]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  //tell webGL to use the program
  gl.useProgram(program);

  //enable the vertex attribute array
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionAttributeLocation);

  //tell webgl how to pull out the data
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionAttributeLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

  //render
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
}
```

```css
canvas{outline:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>WebGL demo</title>
 </head>
 <body onload="start();">
  <canvas id="webgl_canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
 </body>
</html>
```